# Draw a graph indicating the weight of each arc

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to draw a small graph indicating its weights in the arcs. For example, the following code:

```
library(igraph)
actors <- data.frame(name=c("0","1","2", "3", "4", "5","6"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("0", "0", "1", "2", "3", "3","4","5","4"),
                          to=c("1", "2", "3", "3", "5", "4","5","6","6"),
                        weight=c(2,6,5,8,15,10,6,6,2))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=F, vertices=actors)
plot(g)
```

draws the graph without the information about weights:
[image]
How could I insert this information on the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set_edge_attr` to assign `weight` to the `width` (or `label`) attribute, e.g.,

```
g %>%
  set_edge_attr(name = "width", value = relations$weight) %>%
  plot()
```

or

```
g %>%
  set_edge_attr(name = "label", value = relations$weight) %>%
  plot()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to represent edge weight as thickness you can do:

```r
plot(g, edge.width = relations$weight)
```

[image]

If you want to use labels you can do:

```r
plot(g, edge.label = relations$weight)
```

[image]

Of course you can combine these and tweak the size, color etc. The full list of layout parameters is in the `igraph` [plot docs](https://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html).